# Ruby Spreadsheet not opening remote file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spreadsheet

I am trying to open a spreadsheet stored remotely using the Ruby Spreadsheet gem. My code is as follows

```
require 'spreadsheet'
require 'open-uri'

book = Spreadsheet.open(url)
```

It is returning me an error of Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory

By putting the url into the browser, it downloads fine, so I know the url is fine. I have some very similar code using FasterCSV which works absolutely fine, so wandering if this is an issue with Spreadsheet, or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I dont thing remote file can open using `Spreadsheet xls` try downloading it and then open it correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I'm not aware that open-uri would change open calls in arbitrary classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not using `open-uri`, which will fetch the URL and expose it as a `StringIO` object (which works like an `IO` object in most cases). The `Spreadsheet` class may work if you do this instead:

```
book = Spreadsheet.open(open(url))
```

The second `open` is from `OpenURI` which will send the `StringIO` object to `Spreadsheet.open`.

Comment: That's worked a treat. I didn't realise that I wasn't using open-uri originally, but it makes total sense now

Comment: I tried it with open(url), now it says: Error reading file: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - #

Comment: @Varun did you require `open-uri`?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell of the source, at https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/lib/spreadsheet.rb,
you'll need to download the file before opening it. The open method on the Spreadsheet class expects an IO object or a physical path on disk:

`def open io_or_path, mode="rb+"
   ...`